# Do languages in $\mathsf{coRE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$ have Turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

What can we say about languages in $\mathsf{coRE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$? Are there Turing machines for these languages?

I know that $\overline{HP} \in \mathsf{coRE}$ doesn't have a Turing machine, and also that all the language that do have Turing machines are in $\mathsf{RE}$, so is it true that for any language that is in $\mathsf{coRE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$ there's isn't a Turing machine? I wonder why is that so, can someone elaborate?

Comment: Turing machines are named after Alan M. Turing. They have nothing to do with the concept of "turning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can associate a language to a Turing machine in several ways.

If the Turing machine halts on all inputs, then the language *accepted* by the Turing machine consists of all words which cause the Turing machine to halt in an accepting state. The class $\mathsf{R}$ consists of all languages which are accepted by some Turing machine.

For an arbitrary Turing machine, the language *recognized* by the Turing machine consists of all words that cause the Turing machine to halt (in any state). The class $\mathsf{RE}$ consists of all languages which are recognized by some Turing machine.

If $L \in \mathsf{coRE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$, then in particular $L \notin \mathsf{R}$, and so no Turing machine accepts $L$. If $L$ were recognized by some Turing machine then $L \in \mathsf{RE}$. However, this is impossible, since then $L \in \mathsf{RE} \cap \mathsf{coRE} = \mathsf{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand on the first sentence of Yuval Filmus' answer:

> We can associate a language to a Turing machine in several ways.

Yuval mentions two: *acceptance* (which characterizes $\mathsf{R}$) and *recognition* (which characterizes $\mathsf{RE}$). There are others, however. Most obviously, we could consider "co-recognition" - say that a Turing machine $M$ "co-recognizes" a language $L$ if the strings in $L$ are exactly the strings on which $M$ does *not* halt. Then of course co-recognition characterizes $\mathsf{coRE}$.

However, that's a bit unnatural. Much more natural in my opinion is the notion of [**limit computability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit). Phrased in terms of natural numbers for simplicity, this is the following:

> A function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is **limit computable** iff there is a computable function $h:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $$f(x)=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty} h(x,s),$$ or more precisely such that for all $x$ there is some $n$ such that for all $s>n$ we have $h(x,s)=f(x)$.

A *set* $X$ is limit computable, meanwhile, iff there is some limit computable function $f$ such that $X=\{i: f(i)=1\}$. (There are many other equivalent formulations of this.)

It turns out that limit computability has a very nice alternate characterization:

> **(Shoenfield)** A function $f$ is limit computable iff it is computable [relative to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) the halting problem [$\emptyset'$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump).

(And via [Post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem) we get another characterization in terms of "definitional complexity.")

Of course this includes both $\mathsf{RE}$ and $\mathsf{coRE}$, and much more besides: there are sets computable relative to the halting problem which are not Turing equivalent to any set in $\mathsf{RE}$. (This is hard to prove!)

And there are even more ways to assign languages to sets; for example, we can talk about "limit recognizability" (which is to limit computability as recognizability is to acceptance), which gives us the [$\Sigma^0_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) languages.